# Using Camel with Spring-boot to build a REST Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

Basically, I want to be able to post an object in JSON and print the details of this object using Java.

In order to o that I want (and I have to) use SPRING-BOOT and Camel

This is the class representing my object :

```
    public class Response {
    private long id;
    private String content;

    public Response(){

    }

    public Response(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content){
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

Then I have a Rest Controller :

```
    @RestController
public class BasicController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    //Handle a get request 
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public Response getResponse(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        System.out.println("Handle by spring");
        return new Response(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }

    //Handle a post request
    @RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Response> update(@RequestBody Response rep) {

        if (rep != null) {
            rep.setContent("HANDLE BY SPRING");
        }  
        return new ResponseEntity<Response>(rep, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

With this code i'm able to handle a post request and print detail BUT I have to use Camel. So I tryed the following :

1) I added a bean conf

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{

    private static final String CAMEL_URL_MAPPING = "/camel/*";
    private static final String CAMEL_SERVLET_NAME = "CamelServlet";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), CAMEL_URL_MAPPING);
        registration.setName(CAMEL_SERVLET_NAME);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

2) Then I created 2 routes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<!--      <route id="test"> -->
<!--          <from uri="timer://trigger"/> -->
<!--          <to uri="log:out"/> -->
<!--      </route> -->
     <route id="test2">
         <from uri="servlet:///test"/>
         <to uri="log:Handle by camel"/>
     </route>
 </routes>
```

With this I'm able to hand a request on camel. BUT I don't know how to make the link between Spring and camel. Is there a way to handle a request with my spring controller and then call a camel route? On the same URL..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use autowired `producerTemplate` to call Camel routes. It will be created if you add   the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version> <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

For more info you can see Camel documentation [here](http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html).

In your case you would call something like:

```
producerTemplate.sendBody...
```